# Printing numbers from 1-1000 as words in Python

Tags: python

Python beginner here and trying to make a program that prints numbers from 1-1000 as words in Python. I found this kind of solution to print from 1-100:

```
digits = ['one', 'two',   'three', 'four', 'five', 
          'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

teens = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 
          'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']

tens = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'fourty', 'fifty', 
          'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']

for word in digits + teens:
    print(word)

for tens_word in tens:
    print(tens_word)        # e.g. twenty

    for digits_word in digits:
        print(tens_word, digits_word)   # e.g. twenty one

print("one hundred")
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
... (between rows)
ninety eight
ninety nine
one hundred
```

How to add more code to this program that it counts to 1-1000?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/num2words/.  You can use this

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Maybe try understanding how it works and adding on to it to extend it?

Comment: @Prune, yes you are right. I tried to edit the code but could not find the solution and I should have posted the code here that I was working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is clearly new to writing loops, I think a more simple approach is warranted. Here is some code.

```
digits = ['one', 'two',   'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
teens  = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', *[d+'teen' for d in digits[5:]]]
tens   = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'fourty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']

# One digit printing
for one in digits:
    print(one)

# Two digit printing
for teen in teens:
    print(teen)
for ten in tens:
    print(ten)          
    for one in digits:
        print(ten, one) 

# Three digit printing
hundred_word = 'hundred'
for hundred in digits:
    print(hundred, hundred_word)
    for one in digits:
        print(hundred, hundred_word, one)
    for teen in teens:
        print(hundred, hundred_word, teen)
    for ten in tens:
        print(hundred, hundred_word, ten)
        for one in digits:
            print(hundred, hundred_word, ten, one)
```

Hopefully it is clear that there is a lot of redudency. It makes you wonder if you could simplify this process by writing a "function" so that you don't have to constantly re-write the same repeated code. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this! At the moment, the learning material that I am following has not yet gone through functions, and it's coming next.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from num2words import num2words
for e in range(1,1000):
    print(num2words(e))
```

if you want solution without num2words

```
num2words1 = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', \
            6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten', \
            11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', \
            15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen', 19: 'Nineteen'}
num2words2 = ['Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety']

def number(Number):
    if 0 <= Number <= 19:
        return num2words1[Number]
    elif 20 <= Number <= 99:
        tens, remainder = divmod(Number, 10)
        return num2words2[tens - 2] + '-' + num2words1[remainder] if remainder else num2words2[tens - 2]
   

def main():
    for e in range(1,1000):
        print(number(e))
main()
```